# Bit of javascript throwing an error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this bit on code in my website.

```
    </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(window).bind("load", function() {
        document.getElementById('loadercircle').style.display = 'none'
        });
    </script>
```

All it does is hide a html element.

**Webpage error details**

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 16:47:24 UTC
>
> Message: Object expected
>   Line: 99
>   Char: 6
>   Code: 0
>
> Line 99 is:                document.getElementById('loadercircle').style.display = 'none'

Any idea why that is erroring out IE?

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="loadercircle"` in the document?  Are you using anything like ASP.NET that might be giving the `id` a different name (i.e. `ctl01_loadercircle`)?

Comment: Is there any script tag before the first `</script>`?

Comment: Yes there is another script before hand, sorry about pasting it. There is a element with the loadercircle ID in the document. I'll try the below solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are including jQuery in your page?

```
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
```

Seems to work fine for me, however note if you want this to run when the DOM has finished loading you should use the following:

HTML

```
<div id="loadercircle">Loader Circle</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('loadercircle').style.display = 'none'
});
```

Also an easy way to hide the element with jQuery would be:

```
$('#loadercircle').hide();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4HVV/1/

Comment: this line gives me an error or warning:
 $('#loadercircle').hide();

with the warning:Message: 'null' is null or not an object

Comment: are you definitely loading the jQuery library in your code? Have you got a reference to jquery-1.10.2.min.js? or a similar .js file?

Answer (score 0):

I would change to

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
 $('#loadercircle').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `document.getElementById('loadercircle')` doesn't return a HTML element. Does the element you want to remove have the property `id="loadercircle"`?

By the way: You seem to be using jQuery, so you can just do `$('#loadercircle').hide()`. When the element isn't found, it will do nothing and not throw an error.

Comment: It should, its an iframe.
  <iframe id="loadercircle" src="loader.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Answer (score -2):

Did you check the semicolan?

```
document.getElementById('loadercircle').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Semicolon is not necessary!

Comment: As it is the last statement of the function.